# create dynamic it in protractor depending on result of a promise

Tags: typescript, protractor

In protractor I want to achieve below steps:

1. in appconfigts , read excel file.
2. create sperate it for each row in that excel.

```
   ---start----- 

describe
 {
 let wb= new workbook():
 let configsheet;
 let fileName = 'excel_file.xlsx';
  //read excel and find rowcount 
wb.readFile(fileName).then(function(){
let ws= wb.getWorksheet('Configuration');
let configsheet= ws;
console.log(configsheet.rowCount);
});

for(let i=0;i<configsheet.rowCount;i++){
it('it'+i,function(){
console.log(i);
});
}

});

----end----``
```

Answer (score 0):

While its theoretically possible to meddle with the way `describe` and `it` blocks are created/executed, i am at a loss to understand why you want to complicate it that way.

In any case, you can have a look at https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/620#issuecomment-72956621 to see if that fits the bill.

**UPDATE**

Its not possible to come up with a solution without knowing what API you are using for reading excel file.

Let me give some pointers: a Promise gets fulfilled (or rejected) in future. The promise object lets you get notified about it and do something with the value it returns.

In your case you are reading an Excel and the Promise (if the library is meaningful) will give you the rows from the excel as part of successful fulfilment. With that said, you just have to invert the code you have i.e. don't use the promise inside the `it` creation but create `it`s after excel is read successfully

```
readExcel(file, sheetName).then((rows) => {
    for(int i = 0; i <= rows.length; i++){
     it('i:'+i, function ());
    }
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My requirement is  to read excel then calcilate rowcount of sheet and then create multiple it blocks as per the rowcount. but read excel is promise function so it is returning row count later. and i am not able create multiple it blocks  as per rowcount. can you help with the solution

Comment: @user9596894 Updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: I am using exceljs library to read excel. but it wont allow me to create it inside promise function. I have tried the solution earlier also. but it didnt work.

Comment: @user9596894 Gently to put (and as mentioned in the answer), its not possible to help you without knowing what you tried to do and what error you encountered. Please do update the question with the code you are trying and the error you are getting. `exceljs` is a wonderful library and its fair to expect that following basic case works as expected `worksheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber) {console.log('Row ' + rowNumber + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(row.values));});` by returning the rows.